# WebDashBoard on Mono

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

Hosted the CruiseControl.Net 1.6 on XSP4 on Mono 2.8 .
While hitting the dashboard , the below error is thrown

Could not load type 'ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Config.Preprocessor.Evaluator' from assembly 'ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Went back to CruiseControl.NET 1.5 and that works. I guess 1.6 is not quite compatible with Mono.